# Not able to Start SignalR server in WPF

Tags: wpf, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to start the SignalR server , when I am starting the WPF application. So that clients can communicate. I have below code in WPF.

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                      .ConfigureServices(ConfigureRequiredServices(e))
                      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                      .UseUrls("http://localhost:5059")
                      .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSignalR())
                      .Configure(app => {
                          app.UseRouting();
                          app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => { endpoint.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub"); });
                      }))
                      .Build();

        await AppHost!.StartAsync();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Now when I am trying to reach to signalR server from console app, I am not able to do that. Any idea what I am missing?

Client code:

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                          .WithUrl("http://localhost:5059/myhub")
                          .Build();

connection.StartAsync();
connection.SendAsync("SendMessege", "A Message from Client");

connection.On<String>("ReceiveMessege", x => Console.Write(x));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Perhaps "SendMessege" and "ReceiveMessege" should be "SendMessage" and "ReceiveMessage".

Comment: Call `connection.On...` before you call `StartAsync` and `SendAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Basically, ConfigureWebHostDefaults should precede, ConfigureServices. So below code works and able to get the server call. No change in the client.

```
AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                          .UseUrls("http://localhost:5059")
                          .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSignalR())
                          .Configure(app => {
                              app.UseRouting();
                              app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => { endpoint.MapHub<MyHub>("/myhub");});
                          }))
                          .ConfigureServices(ConfigureRequiredServices(e))
                          .Build();
```